# Ajax check if Url exists then redirect

Tags: ajax, jquery

Sorry to ask such a basic question. I would like to add an Ajax feature to my input page which does:

1. use the `blockUI` plugin to add a popup window which tells users to wait
2. in the meanwhile ajax detects the existence of output page
3. if calculations are finished, ajax redirects the browser to the output page (`batchoutput.html`)

If everything goes well, the popup message will appear for around 1-2 mins until the calculations are done, then the browser will be redirected to the `batchoutput.html` page.

However, the situation is: the popup message window appears only for a second, then after a min or two the browser goes to the `batchoutput.html`. My guess is something is wrong with my ajax function. It seems like the `ajaxstart` and `ajaxstop` are misfired. Can I have some suggestions?

Here is the code:

```
$('.input1_button').click(function () {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $.blockUI({ css: { 
            border: 'none', 
            padding: '15px', 
            backgroundColor: '#000', 
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
            opacity: .5, 
            color: '#fff' 
        } }); 
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
        $.unblockUI();
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/batchoutput.html",
        data: $(".articles").serialize(),
        dataType: "html",
       success: function() {
            window.location = '/batchoutput.html';
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ajaxStop` is fired right after the ajax request is *complete*, and *complete* means error **or** success.

Therefore, what happens after you click a button is:

- `ajaxStart` is fired, causing UI to block
- ajax request to `/batchoutput.html` is performed
- if request fails, `ajaxStop` is fired, causing UI to unblock

My suggestion is to:

- block UI on button click (i.e. move `$.blockUI` directly into `click` function)
- after that, send ajax request repeatedly until it finishes with success (you can use Javascript's native function `setInterval` or trigger next request on `ajaxError`)
- when request succeds, unblock UI and redirect (this can be done either directly in `success` callback or in `ajaxSuccess` method)

Comment: Thanks Michael. I think removing ajaxstop and move unblock UI into success work!